# if statement not working when i try to use it in my code to check a variable

Tags: javascript, if-statement, console

i am trying to detect what the variable is but it is not working

```
var question = prompt("press 1 for hi logged in console and press anything else for goodbye logged in console")
if (question ===1
)  {
console.log("hi")
}else{
console.log("goodbye")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how `==` and `===` are different. You compare by `===` and it compares both value and type. `prompt` always returns string and '1' is not same as 1. So you either need to use `==` or compare as `question === '1'`.

Answer (score 0):

prompt returns a string, you care compare the return value `question` to the value `1` as string as follows:

```js
var question = prompt("press 1 for hi logged in console and press anything else for goodbye logged in console")
if (question === "1"
)  {
console.log("hi")
}else{
console.log("goodbye")
}
```

Comment: i get it now if statements are easy